# Restricting characters of a string

Tags: python, character

I am having some problems trying to write a program, that takes in an input (string) and checks the amount of characters in the string. The string should be able to tell wether the message contains over or under 160 characters. 
I have written the code, but it will not run. Can anybody help me?
My best guess was to use the len() function and then an if or else statement. Would this be the correct way of doing it? And how do I make the if and else statement know, that the number I'm getting from the len() is the the number of characters?

I hope this makes a bit of sense...

As you probable have guessed, I am pretty new at Python...
Hope that you all understand my question, else feel free to ask!

My code:

```
def CharacterRestriction(): 
    print("Welcome to the chat. Maximun amount of characters is: 160") 
    len(Message) = input("Enter your message:") 
    print ("The lenght of the message is:", len(Message)) 
    if len(Message) <= 160: 
        print(Message) 
    else: 
        len(Message) > 160 
        print ("Maximum amount of characters are 160") 
        CharacterRestriction()
```

Comment: How can we help figure out what is wrong with your code if you do not show us your code?

Comment: I'd post code you wrote highlighting points where you're in doubt. Like this it's hard to say where you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Sorry. I could figure out how to post it in the original post, but here it is:

Comment: def CharacterRestriction():
    print("Welcome to the chat. Maximun amount of characters is: 160")
    len(Message) = input("Enter your message:")

print ("The lenght of the message is:", len(Message))

    if len(Message) <= 160:
        print(Message)

    else: len(Message) > 160
        print ("Maximum amount of characters are 160")

CharacterRestriction()

Comment: That came out funny, but I hope you can read it?!

Comment: @PeterPeters Please edit your original post with your code, it will let you format it properly.

Comment: It is Message = input("Enter your message:")

Answer (score 2):

Method after correcting:

```
def CharacterRestriction(): 
    print("Welcome to the chat. Maximun amount of characters is: 160") 
    Message = input("Enter your message:") 
    print ("The lenght of the message is:", len(Message)) 
    if len(Message) <= 160: 
        print(Message) 
    else: 
        print("Maximum amount of characters are 160")
```

Comment: You don't need the elif part condition, as the message will always be in that case more than 160 characters long.

Comment: Consider using lowercase to variable names such as Message and method names such as CharacterRestriction (it's a [convention](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) used by Python developers). And be careful using input(), as it can evaluate any arbitrary code, in your example, I'd use [raw_input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead.

Comment: It would be helpful to explain **what you corrected** and, more importantly, **why**.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you! And if I want to show only the first 160 characters if the message is longer than 160, should I then use the range function or?

Comment: use print(Message[:160])